# After several successes, Elasticsearch queries suddenly fail

Tags: perl, elasticsearch, bigdata

I've written a Perl script that, put simply, will pull data from an Elasticsearch database and print it out in a specific format.

*If any particular snippets of code would be helpful to see in solving my issue, let me know and I'll be more than happy to post them here. I won't cut and paste the whole script as it is almost 1000 lines long & it's my company's property.*

*Modules currently used:* strict, warnings, LWP::UserAgent, CGI, POSIX, JSON, Modern::Perl, Term::ANSIColor, & Scalar::Util

**Declarations and such:**

```
# Declare user agent object
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

# Set custom HTTP request header fields
my $req = HTTP::Request->new( POST => $serverEndpoint );
$req->header( 'content-type' => 'application/json' );

my $post_data = '{ 
        "fields" : [' . $arrayList . '],
        "sort" : [
            { "@timestamp" : { "order" : "asc" } }
        ],
        "query" : {
            "filtered" : {
                "filter" : {
                    "range" : {
                        "@timestamp" : {
                            "gte" : "' . $lowerBound . '",
                            "lte" : "' . $upperBound . '"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }';
```

$arrayList is previously defined to be a string of fields with quotes around them (e.g. "field1","field2","field3").

```
# Receives results from ES (this is Perl syntax for querying ES)
    $req->content( $post_data );
    $resp = $ua->request( $req );
    $myResults = $resp->content();
    #say $myResults; die;

    # Changes string (as returned by http request) to JSON format that is compatible with Perl
    $decoded = JSON::XS::decode_json( $myResults );

    @data = @{ $decoded->{ "hits" }{ "hits" } };
    @tempResponse = @data;
    my $lengthOfArray = scalar @tempResponse;
```

**At this point, @data has the information I need. I've checked it, it looks right.** I saved the length of the current response for future use.

```
$scrollID = $decoded->{ "_scroll_id" };
```

I save the scroll ID for the next part.

Now that I have the initial set of data, I repeatedly query the database until (well, at least, it's supposed to) the database has been completely queried.

I can tell when the database has been fully queried if $lengthOfArray < 0. If this is true, then there is no more data to get.

```
while ( $lengthOfArray > 0 ) {
        $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

        $serverEndpoint = "http://localhost:9200/_search/scroll?scroll=1m&scroll_id=" . $scrollID;
        $req = HTTP::Request->new( POST => $serverEndpoint );
        $req->header( 'content-type' => 'application/json' );

        $req->content( $post_data );

        #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!                 
        $resp = $ua->request( $req );
        #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

        $myResults = $resp->content();

        # Changes string (as returned by http request) to JSON format that is compatible with Perl
        $decoded = JSON::XS::decode_json( $myResults );

        @tempResponse = @{ $decoded->{ "hits" }{ "hits" } };
        #print "@tempResponse\n";

        @data = ( @data, @tempResponse );

        $lengthOfArray = scalar @tempResponse;
    }
```

The data set I'm working with is enormous. Everything goes perfectly well (I've tested it. If I only let it run for 600 times through the loop, it works no problem) **until it gets to loop count #801.** At the 801st time through the loop, it gets hung up. It sits there for a good minute or so before dying with the error message:

```
malformed JSON string, neither tag, array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "read timeout at /usr...")
```

I've traced down the error to the line that has all the !!!!!s around it above. The loop gets hung up on that line on the 801st time through the loop.

There are no real indicators as to why this error is happening. Again, it works if I go through the loop 800 times, but not 801.

I know all of the data is in Elasticsearch. There are about 12,000 hashes that I should be getting from it. I can access the first 800 hashes via @data[0], @data[1] etc. but after that I'm out of luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I spent my whole 9-hour work day today trying to figure this out with no luck. Really, if you could even ask for clarification on some part of my explanation that might be enough to find the answer.

So, if there's *anything* I can do to clear up what I've typed (show what the ES URL gives), please let me know.

Thank you very, very much!

**==========================================================**

**EDIT #1:** I've found the source of the problem. It doesn't make sense, but here it is.

In $post_data I have $arrayList. It contains a list of 36 fields that I had previously taken from an array of fields. It's formatted like this:

```
"field1","field2","field3","field4"
```

I noticed that if I remove ONE of those fields, doesn't matter which one, the request goes through without a problem.

It does not matter which field it is.

**==========================================================**

**EDIT #2:** This may be useful. If I let the request time out, it gives the following error message:

```
malformed JSON string, neither tag, array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "read timeout at /usr..." at *scriptName.pl* line 403, <STDIN> line 5.
```

Line 403 is as follows:

```
$decoded = JSON::XS::decode_json( $myResults );
```

It's right below the

```
#!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!                 
$resp = $ua->request( $req );
#!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

**==========================================================**

**EDIT #3:** I tried printing out $resp->content() to see if anything looks strange before it gets hung up. It doesn't initially ... The content looks just like it should.

After awhile, though, it gives up and prints out the following message:

```
{"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures{SearchContextMissingException[No search context found for id [2378]]}{SearchContextMissingException[No search context found for id [2379]]}{SearchContextMissingException[No search context found for id [2380]]}","status:404"}
```

This completely covers the screen until I interrupt it.

**==========================================================**

**FINAL EDIT: IT WORKS!**

Nothing really needed to be changed in the declarations section. I *did* change the size of the query so that less queries had to be made (I think ES's RAM was getting filled). So now this is what the $post_data looks like:

```
my $post_data = '{
        "size": 1000,
        "fields" : [' . $arrayList . '],
        "sort" : [
            { "@timestamp" : { "order" : "asc" } }
        ],
        "query" : {
            "filtered" : {
                "filter" : {
                    "range" : {
                        "@timestamp" : {
                            "gte" : "' . $lowerBound . '",
                            "lte" : "' . $upperBound . '"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }';
```

Notice how the size has been changed near the top. I don't think that this was what fixed my issue, but it should help performance, anyway.

The problem I believe I was having was with the while loop. Originally the loop was designed to continue to run until the hits array was empty, but for some reason it kept going even after that. No idea why, maybe I'll figure that out later.

What I did instead was check to see if one of the members that I expect to find within the hits array is defined. If it isn't defined, it fails the loop.

There were a couple other minor changes, but that was the real big one. It works great now! ... only 2 days later.

Thanks Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

every scroll request should use the most recent  [scroll id](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#CO4-4) 
i.e scroll_id returned in previous scroll response.

Looking from the code excerpt looks like you are using the the scroll id from the first response probably changing that to use the most recent scroll_id should help

i.e. in the *while* block you would need   **$scrollID =  $decoded->{ "_scroll_id" };**

```
while ( $lengthOfArray > 0 ) {
        $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

        $serverEndpoint = "http://localhost:9200/_search/scroll?scroll=1m&scroll_id=" . $scrollID;
        $req = HTTP::Request->new( POST => $serverEndpoint );
        $req->header( 'content-type' => 'application/json' );

        $req->content( $post_data );

        #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!                 
        $resp = $ua->request( $req );
        #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

        $myResults = $resp->content();

        # Changes string (as returned by http request) to JSON format that is compatible with Perl
        $decoded = JSON::XS::decode_json( $myResults );
        $scrollID =  $decoded->{ "_scroll_id" };
        @tempResponse = @{ $decoded->{ "hits" }{ "hits" } };
        #print "@tempResponse\n";

        @data = ( @data, @tempResponse );

        $lengthOfArray = scalar @tempResponse;
    }
```

probably this should help.

Comment: I tried that, and it still gets hung up at the 801st query.

Comment: @kgrimes2 did you try looking in the es cluster logs was  there any error message or garbage collection activity ? The fact that it always occurs at 801 iteration is odd

Comment: I've narrowed it down slightly. I've noticed that if I remove one of the fields from the $arrayList that's getting posted, it works fine. It doesn't matter which one is removed. Just one has to be removed for it to work.

Comment: If I let the request time out, it gives the following error message: 

"malformed JSON string, neither tag, array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "read timeout at /usr...") at scriptName.pl line 403, <STDIN> line 5.

I've updated above along with what line 403 is

Comment: in the code check for [$resp->is_success](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/HTTP-Message-6.10/lib/HTTP/Response.pm) before calling decode json if not successfull die $resp->content() this way you would get the actual message returned from server and not the json decode error

Comment: strange and interesting probably the es cluster logs may have more info is that something you can access ?

Comment: I added  the $resp->is_success line right before calling decode_json. It returns a 1 several times before freezing and not putting out anything at all. I have access to the elasticsearch.log file, is that what you mean? Or a different one? I'm running ES as a service

Comment: I've tried adding die unless $resp->is_success all over the code. It never dies. Just times out.

Comment: yes elasticsearch.log is there any message logged during the failure

Comment: no search context  essentially means the [scroll_id](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#_clear_scroll_api) got cleared are you sure you have not recieved all the documents how many documents are you expecting and how man you retrieve in each scroll request  is it the default 10 ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to tell if I've gotten all the responses. As you can see above, I have a while loop going on that should keep going as long as there's something in @tempResponse. Maybe this is wrong? Is there a better way to go about it? I should get about 12,000 documents, and I'm currently getting 10 each scroll request.

Comment: relying on size of hits array sounds right , i can't figure whats wrong try increasing the scroll timeout from 1m  to a higher value and see if that helps ?

Comment: It's weird. I changed the size to 1000 just to see what happened and I'm checking the size of the hits.hits array every time. It says it has a size of 1000... even when it doesn't actually have anything in it.

Comment: strange are there any garbage collection messages in elasticsearch.log ?

Comment: I FINALLY got it. See the last edit for details. Thank you SO MUCH for your help!!